# Context aware kerning in siunitx with per-mode?

Tags: siunitx, kerning

Assume I want to type in the units for irradiance (radiant flux (power) received by a surface per unit area). I can do this as follows

```
\si[per-mode=symbol]{\watt\per\m\squared}
```

[image]

However, the kerning between `W` and `/` is *bad*. Luckilly this can be remedied by removing a small space

```
\si[per-mode=symbol]{\watt\!\per\m\squared}
```

[image]

Alas, inserting this space, breaks the contexst aware setting `per-mode=symbol`.

```
\si{\watt\!\per\m\squared}
```

[image]

Which is not what I expected. I was thinking it should expand to

[image]

**Is it possible to add some kerning before / after slanted units `Å`, `A` `V`, `W` when combined with `per-mode=symbol`?**

Are there some ISO restrictions against adding kerning between / and units, I am not aware off?

The examples in my document below looks bad, however all I want is that the space before and after / should be the same. The `\volt\per\angstrom` comes too close if we use `\!`.

## Examples.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\si{\watt\per\m\squared}

\si[per-mode=symbol]{\watt\per\m\squared}

\si{\watt\!\per\m\squared}

\si[per-mode=symbol]{\watt\!\per\m\squared} 

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\si{\volt\per\angstrom}

\si[per-mode=symbol]{\volt\per\angstrom}

\si{\volt\!\per\!\angstrom}

\si[per-mode=symbol]{\volt\!\per\!\angstrom}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\si{\m\squared\per\ampere}

\si[per-mode=symbol]{\m\squared\per\ampere}

\si{\m\squared\per\!\ampere}

\si[per-mode=symbol]{\m\squared\!\per\ampere}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you use `\DeclareSIQualfier` from the `siuntix` package? For example, If you declare  `\DeclareSIQualifier\sitighten{\!}` in the preamble and then you write `\si{\watt\sitighten\per\m\squared}`, I believe it fixes the context aware issue that you described. But I am not certain that this addresses _all_ of the issues you were discussing.